# Someone who forms their own opinion

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for someone who forms their own opinion based entirely on their personal experience, without having been influenced by any outside source?

Comment: What connotation do you want the word to convey: a positive, neutral, or negative connotation?

Comment: Nowadays this is no longer true, but etymologically the word *heretic* means that, more or less.

Comment: You need to distinguish between someone who is not influenced by the *opinions* of others, and someone who is not influenced by *facts* and *information* from outside his own head.  The first is some variation of "free thinker", while the second is in a state of self-imposed ignorance.

Answer (score 12):

I'd probably use:

> [free-thinker](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/freethinker)

Answer (score 6):

You might well be looking for the words "independent thinker".

Answer (score 2):

A related word is *[autogenic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autogenic)*, an adjective indicating something is self-produced.  One might apply the term *autogenicist* to a person who has been informed solely by his or her own experience.

Whatever name you give the self-informed person,  *[autodidact](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autodidact#Noun)* (“A self-taught person; an automath”) is a [hypernym](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypernym) of that name.  That is, the set of  self-informed persons is a subset of the set of autodidacts.

Two previously-suggested terms are useful in spite of being ignored or voted down.   *[Empiricism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empiricism)* (“A pursuit of knowledge purely through experience, especially by means of observation and sometimes by experimentation”) is directly relevant, and leads to the suggestion *empiricist*.   *[Solipsism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solipsism)* (“The theory that the self is all that exists or that can be proven to exist” or “Self-absorption, an unawareness of the views or needs of others”) is slightly less relevant, but for someone to be completely self-informed, it is probable that person must be solipsistic or a [hermit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hermit#Noun) or deranged or [autistic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autistic) or perhaps a genius.

Answer (score 1):

"He is his own man."

"A self made man."

"A man of the world."

"Educated in the University of Life".

Opinionated

Arrogant

Self obsessed

Uneducated

Ignorant

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts you can use:

> Possibly the most controversial feature of the solipsistic worldview
>   is the denial of the existence of other minds. Since personal
>   experiences are private and ineffable, another being's experience can
>   be known only by analogy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism

Answer (score 0):

A man that forms his own opinion should be open to hear opinion of the others and then to make his own. How a man can make his opinion without been influenced by any outside source as he has his social and education "environment" by default ? Your question is not exactly clear about that.

My suggestion is  [open-minded](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/open-minded) man.

Comment: Your first sentence is sensible. But open-mindedness is not the same as what OP is asking for; indeed, very many bigoted opinions stem from over-generalising personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

Intuition has [the following definitions:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intuition)

> a.
>   an immediate cognition of an object not inferred or determined by a previous cognition of the same object.
>
> b.
>   any object or truth so discerned.
>
> c.
>   **pure, untaught, noninferential knowledge.** (*emphasis mine*)

I think you could say that "a person who forms their own opinion based entirely on their personal experience, without having been influenced by any outside source" is [*intuitional*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intuitional?s=t) or [*intuitive*.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/%2aintuitive%2a?s=t)

Answer (score 0):

Unadulterated : ([Source](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unadulterated?q=unadulterated))

> *adjective*
>
> not mixed or diluted with any different or extra elements; complete and absolute

"He is of an *unadulterated* mind."

Or

Independent : ([Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/independent))

> *adj*
>
> 1. Not governed by a foreign power; self-governing.
> 2. Free from the influence, guidance, or control of another or others; self-reliant
> 3. Not determined or influenced by someone or something else; not contingent

"He considers himself an *independent*, having formed his own thoughts and views without any whispers in his ear."

---

The above is for your request: "Is there a **single word**[...]?"

(*edits = mine*)